# How can I run a httprequest inside function first thing before page loads?

Tags: javascript, php, html, xmlhttprequest

Ive tried on load atribute in body tag without success

`<body onload=\"updateGroup()\">`

nor function calling inside echo:
`echo "<script> updateGroup(); </script>";`

I'm open to critics!

```
function updateGroup(){
            
            var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = \"../requests/updateGroup.php\";
            http.open(\"POST\", url, true);

            //Send the proper header information along with the request
            http.setRequestHeader(\"Content-type\", \"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\");

            http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
              if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                
              }
            }
            http.send();
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what your looking for is an [iife](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). This should run even before document.ready

```
(updateGroup() {
 ....
})();
```